# How to convert text number to integer type in psql query

Tags: postgresql, psqlodbc

I'm trying to run a query as such

```
select * from mytable where to_number(minutesintext, '9999') >= 10;

expected result:
col1 | col2 | col3 | minutesintext
-------------------------------------
a    | b    | c    | 11
f    | g    | e    | 98
```

But I'm constantly hit with this error:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "
```

I've seen the example usage for to_number() have all been:

```
select to_number('45', '9999');

results in:
45
```

And cant seem to find examples where to_number() function is used as part of the conditional clause.
What am I doing wrong? and how can I query all rows while converting integers (stored as text) into numbers *during* the query.

*Changing the data type of the column is out of the question as it needs to be stored as text.

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.1 on my local and PostgreSQL 11 on remote environment

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Generally this works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b9ae2e7f6c3008a916b0c8d34caa448 However, it seems like you have a record where you have an empty string, which - naturally - cannot be interpreted as a number

Comment: Why not `select '45'::integer, nullif('','')::integer;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this works: [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b9ae2e7f6c3008a916b0c8d34caa448)

However, your error message says: It seems like you have a record where you have an empty string, which - naturally - cannot be interpreted as a number.

To avoid this, you could add some fixing logic, like adding `NULLIF()` function:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09c982fecd1ad9e1b08e873f47a55fce)

```
select * from mytable 
where to_number(
    NULLIF(minutesintext, ' '), '9999'
) >= 10;
```

If you don't need to parse a specific number format, you can simply cast the (escaped) text into type `int`:

```
select * from mytable 
where NULLIF(minutesintext, ' ')::int >= 10;
```

Comment: thanks the second query works and is best for my scenario!

Comment: @Syabster consider accepting the answer, so that other users can also profit from it.